# Making rsync backup /var makes the system unstable

Tags: rsync, backup

I just got a new backup device, and I wanted to start using it with rsync, so I back things up, and the system decides to completely not boot at all. (Here's that question: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312214/why-does-rsync-cause-my-system-to-fail-booting))

But I solved that problem by omitting the /var directory, but I need to backup things in /var like the www/ directory and other things. How would I go about doing that?

Here's my current rsync code:

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found","/BTSync","/home/cloud7/torrent"} / /mnt/backup/cloud7
```

Comment: Why the downvotes, people? It seems a perfectly reasonable question to ask, even if it does appear to be a strange situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself, I excluded `/var/run` (which was a link to /run) and `/var/lock` (same deal).

Comment: Do you know why tickling these directories should cause your system to fail to boot? Is it a causal relationship or just coincidence?

Comment: Because the system is constantly accessing these files, and with rsync, its possible that upon reading a file that something else is writing to, the file could get corrupted.

Comment: There's no way that reading a file will corrupt it. And Linux systems don't mandate reader/writer locks so the act of reading won't prevent writing. You might get a corrupted backup for `rsync` if the file is being update at the instant the read is happening, but that wouldn't cause a boot failure. Hence my curiousity to understand what's going on.

Comment: I know it's strange, but a few sources actually say this. I also kept getting this email when I ran commands on the system after rsync backup:

`cloud7-media : Sep 25 21:43:31 : cloud7 : unable to open /var/lib/sudo/cloud7/3 : Read-only file system ; TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/cloud7 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=smartctl -A /dev/sdc`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than exclude specific paths, exclude mount points. It doesn't make sense to back up non-stored filesystems such as tmpfs (used for `/tmp`, `/dev`, `/var/run`, etc. on most modern systems), procfs, sysfs, etc. This also excludes external media.

```
rsync -aAX -x -v --exclude={/lost+found,/BTSync,/home/cloud7/torrent} / /mnt/backup/cloud7
```

If your system has multiple partitions, you'll need to back them all up. For example, if `/home` is a separate partition:

```
rsync -aAX -x -v --exclude={/lost+found,/BTSync,/home/cloud7/torrent} / /mnt/backup/cloud7/
rsync -aAX -x -v --exclude={/lost+found,/BTSync,/home/cloud7/torrent} /home/ /mnt/backup/cloud7/home/
```